# Setting a new value to a cookie creates a duplicate cookie - jquery cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue when i am trying to delete a cookie if i have set it on a different page. Here is the scenario:

I am on my homepage and set a cookie value(by adding a product to my basket), i can delete this while i am on that page.

But when i go on a different page and try to delete the same cookie(product), the cookie is created again with the new value, it does not re-set my current cookie.

I am using this code to add/remove the cookie:

```
$(".add-basket").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ean = $(this).attr('ean');
    var value = $(this).attr("value");
    var path = $(this).attr("imgpath");

    if($.cookie("mycookie")==undefined || $.cookie("mycookie")==""){
        $.cookie("mycookie" , ean + "~" + value + "~" + path);
    } else if($.cookie("mycookie").indexOf(ean) == -1 ){
        $.cookie("mycookie",$.cookie("mycookie") + "|" + ean + "~" + value + "~" + path);
    }

});

$(".remove-basket").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ean = $(this).attr('ean');
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    var path = $(this).attr("imgpath");

    var val = ean + "~" + value + "~" + path; //value to be removed
    if ($.cookie("mycookie") !== undefined) {
        var cookie_val = $.cookie("mycookie");
        if (cookie_val.indexOf(val) !== -1) {
            //check value present in cookie
            var arr = cookie_val.split('|'); //remove spaces and split with |
            var index = arr.indexOf(val);//get index of value to be deleted
            arr.splice(index, 1);  //remove value from array 
            $.cookie("mycookie", arr.join('|')); //convert array to sting using join and set value to cookie
        }
    }
```

Am i missing something?

Please help

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the cookie valid domain, try set cookie using:

```
$.cookie("mycookie", 'value', {path: '/'});
```

this will make the cookie valid on the whole site, if this doesn't work, try to clear your old cookie.

Here is example of using JSON:

```
// sample data
var data = [
  { ean: 1, value: 2, path: 3},
  { ean: 1, value: 2, path: 3}
];

// insert data
data.push({ ean:2, value: 3, path: 4});

// save to cookie
$.cookie('mycookie', JSON.stringify(data), {path: '/'});

// load from cookie
data = JSON.parse( $.cookie('mycookie') );
```

So, change your handler to:

```
$(".add-basket").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ean = 1;
    var value = 1;
    var path = 1;
    var cookie = JSON.parse( $.cookie("mycookie") || '[]' );
    cookie.push({
        ean: ean,
        value: value,
        path: path
    });

    $.cookie("mycookie", JSON.stringify(cookie), {path: '/'});
});

$(".remove-basket").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ean = $(this).attr('ean');
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    var path = $(this).attr("imgpath");
    var cookie = JSON.parse( $.cookie("mycookie") || '[]' );

    $.each(cookie, function (index, row) {
        if (row.value == value) {
            cookie.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });

    $.cookie("mycookie", JSON.stringify(cookie), {path: '/'});
}
```

Comment: i did so, when when editing the cookie, it is re-creating the same cookie with the new value

Comment: @Wasiim You mean it doesn't overwrite the old cookie ? I think this is your serialize problem, try using JSON, that will be easily.

Comment: Yes it does not override the old cookie..using serialize - could you plz paste in some code plz...

Comment: seems i have got a workaround, what do you think using:  .escape(raw.join("|")) when editing the cookie

Comment: @Wasiim See update, try use JSON instead your data serialize.

Comment: seems i am having some trouble to integrate the Json in my code :(

Comment: @Wasiim I will have time later, now I need to go =( , so I may help you later.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50006/discussion-between-wasiim-and-wing-leong)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a problem with cookie `Path` being set. From [jQuery Cookie plugin documentation](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#path):

> *By default the path of the cookie is the path of the page where the cookie was created (standard browser behavior).* If you want to make it available for instance across the entire domain use `path: '/'`. Default: path of page where the cookie was created.

Comment: my issue still persists..any help on how i could serialize the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your cookie is only valid on one page? You have to set the pathname for your cookie.

```
$.cookie("mycookie" , ean + "~" + value + "~" + path, { path: '/' } ); // path:'/' is setting a cookie which is valid for all pages on your domain
```

Comment: i have set the cookie as you mentioned:         if($.cookie(cookie)==undefined || $.cookie(cookie)==""){
            $.cookie(cookie , ean + "~" + value + "~" + path , { path: '/' });
        } else if($.cookie(cookie).indexOf(ean) == -1 ){
            $.cookie(cookie,$.cookie(cookie) + "|" + ean + "~" + value + "~" + path , { path: '/' });
        } . But it does not solve the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You dont even need to clear the cookie, just set path same , for instance you can set path as "/" which cookie has scope throughout the application/site. But, if you dont specify path, it will automatically take the path of the current folder where your code file is placed from which you are setting cookie.